# KnockoutObservableArray<T> not getting populated

Tags: knockout.js, typescript, this, knockout-mapping-plugin

Given the following code, why would LookupEditorVM.lookups end up as 'undefined'?

I've verified that the data is coming back, but maybe I'm misunderstanding how ko.mapping works.

**Code:**

```
class LookupEditorVM {
    lookups: KnockoutObservableArray<LookupVM>;

    click(item) {
        this.selected(item)
    }

    constructor(baseURL: string) {
        this.lookups = ko.observableArray<LookupVM>([]);
        $.getJSON(baseURL, (data) => {
            ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this.lookups);
        });

        this.selected = ko.observable(undefined);

    }
}

class LookupVM {
    ID: number;
    Name: string;
    DisplayName: string;
    Description: string;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Knockout Binding Context](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html). Because `click` is on the prototype and is invoked without any explicit `this` context, invoking it loses which class instance it belonged to.

You can also fix this by using an arrow function in your ViewModel definition for any event handlers that will be invoked this way:

```
class LookupEditorVM {
    lookups: KnockoutObservableArray<LookupVM>;
    selected: KnockoutObservable<LookupVM>;

    click = (item) => { // <--- Arrow function preserves 'this'
        this.selected(item)
    }

    constructor(baseURL: string) {
        this.lookups = ko.observableArray<LookupVM>([]);
        $.getJSON(baseURL, (data) => {
            ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this.lookups);
        });

        this.selected = ko.observable(undefined);
    }
}
```

Comment: @4imble: The solution actually worked fine for me. I'd had it figured out for the callback in getJSON, but I hadn't realized I needed to do it for the click as well. Thanks!